# Hibernate 4 + Spring 3.2 + Transaction Manager + No Roll Back in Mysql

Tags: mysql, spring, rollback, spring-transactions, hibernate-4.x

I need some help. I'm have a problem with a transaction with hibernate and spring.
I'm trying to fill up a File table in mysql. My first insert works great, the second doesn't work (but it's normal...). But data from the frist insert are still present in the table. This doesn't fit the concept of transaction. Am i alright on this ?

I think a rollback should be executed the second time i try to insert corrupted data in database ( by corrupted data, i mean data that doesn't match field constraint)
My first insert is ok but as the second insert is "corrupted" the first insert should be rollback and no data should be present in the table.
Or it's not the case. First data , from the first insert are still in the table. It shouldn't be still present?

I tried to look checked /uncheked exception stuff, misconfiguration of @transactionnal without success...

If you have any idea...

Thanks !!

Main.java :

```
    public static void main( String[] args ) throws Exception{

            ApplicationContext appContext = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext(    "classpath:webConfiguration/applicationContext.xml");

            FileBo aFileBo = (FileBo) appContext.getBean("fileBo");
// Data are ok, there is an insert.
File aFile = File (6778687,".bam");             
aFileBo.save(aFile);

// Error is produce here because the ".pdf" value is not tolerated in the enum field we want to fill up. No data is inserted. But a rollback should be done and data inserted before should be erased ?
File anAnotherFile = File (6567887,".pdf");             
aFileBo.save(anAnotherFile);

}
```

FileBoImpl.java

```
public class FileBoImpl implements FileBo{
FileDao fileDao;


public FileDao getFileDao() {
    return fileDao;
}


public void setFileDao(FileDao fileDao) {
    this.fileDao = fileDao;
}

@Transactional// one transaction for multiple operations
public void save(com.clb.genomic.lyon.model.File aFile) {

 fileDao.save(aFile);
}
```

Hibernate.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.2.xsd
http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx 
http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-3.2.xsd
http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans 
http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.2.xsd " >

<!-- Hibernate session factory -->
<bean id="sessionFactory"  class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBean">

<property name="dataSource">
  <ref bean="dataSource"/>
</property>

<property name="hibernateProperties">
   <props>
     <prop key="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect</prop>
     <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">true</prop>
   </props>
 </property>

 <property name="mappingResources">
   ...
  </property>

</bean>

 <tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="transactionManager" /> 

<bean id="transactionManager" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.HibernateTransactionManager">
<property name="sessionFactory" ref="sessionFactory"></property>

</bean>
```

Beans.xml called in applicationContext.xml with  also Hibernate.xml :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.2.xsd
http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx 
http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-3.2.xsd
http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans 
http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.2.xsd">


<!--  Data Access Object -->

<bean id="fileDao" class="com.clb.genomic.lyon.dao.FileDaoImpl" >
    <property name="sessionFactory" ref="sessionFactory"></property>
</bean> 

<!--  Business Object  -->

<bean id="fileBo" class="com.clb.genomic.lyon.bo.FileBoImpl" >
    <property name="fileDao" ref="fileDao"></property>
</bean> 

</beans>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're using two separate transactions here: one to save the first file, and a second one to save the second file. So the first one is already committed when the second one rollbacks.

If you want the two saves to be part of the same transaction, then you should call a single transaction method from main, and save the two files from this method:

```
public static void main( String[] args ) throws Exception{
    ApplicationContext appContext = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext(    "classpath:webConfiguration/applicationContext.xml");

    FileBo aFileBo = (FileBo) appContext.getBean("fileBo");
    // Data are ok, there is an insert.
    File aFile = File (6778687,".bam");    
    File anAnotherFile = File (6567887,".pdf");  

    aFileBo.save(aFile, anotherFile);
}

public class FileBoImpl implements FileBo {
    FileDao fileDao;
    // ...

    @Transactional
    public void save(com.clb.genomic.lyon.model.File aFile, 
                     com.clb.genomic.lyon.model.File bFile) {

        fileDao.save(aFile);
        fileDao.save(bFile);

    }
}
```

Comment: Ok that's clear for me :-)So it makes me wonder how do you handle multiples entities you want to save in the same transaction. In my code, all DaoEntite have a corresponding BoEntitie(as i showed before). When entities have relationship (many to many, one to many etc...) do they are all integrated in the same transaction? Imagine you have something like this Repertory -> File (one to many relationship) and File -> File_Rights -> Rights (many to many relationship) If i do repertoryBo.save(), fileBo.save () and rightsBo.save() ,does it occur in the same transaction because of the relationship?

Comment: Everything done inside a call of a method annotated with Transactional is part of a single transaction. It's (almost) as simple as that. The role of the service layer (what you call BOs) is to provide transactional methods that correspond to something that must be done in a single transaction. If your service layer only has save() methods, it doesn't add anything to the DAO layer. What it should have is methods like transferAmount() which checks the inputs, removes the amount from an account, add the amount to another account and saves an audit log, all in a single transaction.

Comment: I'm still lost in the idea that when you have 3 tables, so 3 pojos class, 3 daos . You want save data for the 3 tables in a global transaction. So you won't design 3 BOs (Services) Class with save method annotated with Transactionnal. Do i need to implement 1 Service class with a method transactionnal to save all of this. Or do i have to use cascade parameter set to "save-update or all' in mapping and relationship pattern to make 3 services works together in the same transaction (in this case there will be 3 save method annoted transactionnal) ? Do you see what i try to understand ? thanks :)